# Which Index Should I Create when using multiple OrderBy

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-indexes, database-optimization, ef-core-2.2

I'm using Entity Framework Core and Reading some data with thousands of records. Each records has many columns, of that columns I'm using 3 (a, b and c) and doing:

`OrderBy(a).ThenBy(b).ThenBy(c);`

And then I'm applying sorting and pagination.

In order to improve speed of that query which kind of index (if any) should I create? Modification of the tables is not as frequent as reading. Should I create one index with the 3 columns? in which order? or one per each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your query uses a WHERE clause also like below ...

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
FROM Table
WHERE ColumnA = 0
ORDER BY Column1, Column2, Column3
```

Then create your index on the following order ColumnA, Column1, Column2, Column3.

If you are using OFFSET FETCH NEXT ROWS ONLY for paging that index still works

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
FROM Table
WHERE ColumnA = 0
ORDER BY Column1, Column2, Column3
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

If your query only has the ORDER BY clause with no WHERE clause, then create the index in the following order Column1, Column2, Column3.